# How to configure ordering for Spring Configuration Classes

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I am trying to have 2 configuration files. say ConfigA and ConfigB. I want Config B to be called first where it is calling ConfigA all time which is causing me some depenedency issues.

I tried @DependsOn @Order @Import but nothing seems to be helpful. Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details on why you need to do this?

Comment: @Configuration Class configA{@public Template methodA(){ }}